# Giving error: MessageDigest cannot be resolved

Tags: android, md5

I am trying to convert a user fed password into a md5 hash. The following code smippet was taken from a weblog. But it is showing error in eclipse (android development):

MessageDigest cannot be resolved.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private String md5(String in) {
    MessageDigest digest;
    try {
        digest = MessageDisgest.getInstance("MD5");
        digest.reset();
        digest.update(in.getBytes());
        byte[] a = digest.digest();
        int len = a.length;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len << 1);
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++) {
            sb.append(Character.forDigit((a[i] & 0xf0) >> 4, 16));
            sb.append(Character.forDigit(a[i] & 0x0f, 16));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) { e.printStackTrace();}
    return null;

}
```

I am not able to find any error. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change `MessageDisgest` to `MessageDigest`